# What is the subtle difference between "I hope" and "I'm hoping"?

Tags: difference, stative-verbs

What is the subtle difference between *I hope* and *I'm hoping*? For example:

> I'm going to the park tomorrow, so **I hope** it won't rain.
>
> I'm going to the park tomorrow, so **I'm hoping** it won't rain.
>
> **I hope** I'll get the job. I really need it.
>
> **I'm hoping** I'll get the job. I really need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only a rhetorical difference.  The "I'm hoping" refers to an emotion that is currently in progress. So this adds "immediacy" to the sentence.  You are referring to feelings that you are currently directly feeling.

On the other hand "hope" is a general statement of fact, it is plainer and less emotive. It would be used for more serious longer-term desires.

Either hope or hoping is reasonable for the first example. I'd usually use "hope" in the second example (as the desire for the job is a longer-term and more serious)